# Why so many python built-in functions has no in-code docs?

Tags: python

`train_kwargs` is a standard python `dict`, I don't know what does `update(...)` do, is it merge the new kwargs into itself or replace all key-values?

So much so that I had to open the browser to check the official online documentation, which seriously affected my efficiency.

There are so many examples of no in-code docs built-in types and built-in functions that I won’t list them all.

[image]

---

Some classes and functions have well in-code docs.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update

Comment: @chepner Not quite true. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the IDE you're using is being silly.

The example you're giving, `dict#update`, [has perfectly fine built-in help provided by Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8182319de33a9519a2f243ac8c35a20ef82a4d2d/Objects/dictobject.c#L4521-L4525), but your IDE isn't providing you with it.

```
$ python
Python 3.12.2 (main, Feb  6 2024, 20:19:44) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help({}.update)

Help on built-in function update:

update(...) method of builtins.dict instance
    D.update([E, ]**F) -> None.  Update D from dict/iterable E and F.
    If E is present and has a .keys() method, then does:  for k in E: D[k] = E[k]
    If E is present and lacks a .keys() method, then does:  for k, v in E: D[k] = v
    In either case, this is followed by: for k in F:  D[k] = F[k]

>>>
```

Comment: Note that I can repro the OP's screenshots in VSCode exactly, with the latest version and that's pretty much one of the biggest IDEs out there, so it would be handy to know how to fix this

Comment: @roganjosh Sure, but that's an entirely different question, which is related to VSCode's Python code intelligence features and not Python.

Comment: Yes, it's VSCode, it sounds like a suck for python hints.